# Scala process logger

Tags: scala, logging

I am following the [example](http://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-handle-stdout-stderr-external-system-commands-scala) for Scala Process Logger by Alvin Alexander which talks about how to handle stdout and stderr from external system commands. I get most part of the example and now understands how to use it but I am finding hard to understand the purpose of `append _`. Can someone please help me in understanding it? The documents is pretty vague for it.

```
#!/bin/sh
exec scala "$0" "$@"
!#
import sys.process._

val stdout = new StringBuilder
val stderr = new StringBuilder
val status = "ls -al FRED" ! ProcessLogger(stdout append _, stderr append _)

println(status)
println("stdout: " + stdout)
println("stderr: " + stderr)
```

Comment: Do you understand the meaning of `stdout append _` ?

Comment: @pedrofurla Yes I do understanding it now, its basically appending the output of command to `stdout`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's how ScalaDoc describes one of the `ProcessLogger` constructors:

```
def apply(fout: (String) ⇒ Unit, ferr: (String) ⇒ Unit): ProcessLogger
```

So it takes two arguments, each taking a `String` input with no output (i.e. `Unit`). The argument `stdout append _` is appending a `String` input (that's the `_`) to a `StringBuilder`.

In other words, `stdout append _` can be rewritten as `str => stdout.append(str)`

Comment: thanks for your comment, the last line of your answer sums it all. Scala allows you to omit dot sometimes, I just didn't understood the syntax. Thanks again for explaining.

Answer (score -1):

```
stdout append _
```

Is equal to:

```
{ _ => stdout.append(_) }
```

Comment: `{ _ => stdout.append(_) }` is not valid Scala syntax.